# MS Access - setup combobox to allow input of data not in the tables

Tags: vba, combobox

I need help with MS Access 2010.

One of the client's requirement is they need to be able to input new data and also be able to have a drop down list of the data existing in the table for selecting using a combobox. Im very new to MS Access, only managed to work around it using online tutorials. Im not too clued up with VBA coding. I have tried swicthng around the properties components, still not working.

please assist.
thanks

Comment: Well aside from you not being 100% clear about what you're looking to do - combo boxes are generally used for displaying present data. care to elaborate on what exactly you need?

Answer (score 0):

That's what I have done. Wanted to allow free entry but still assist the user if value already exists.

One option is to use the data table as source for the combobox RowSource. Set the combobox LimitToList property to No. Then the combobox RowSource would be like:

`SELECT DISTINCT fieldname FROM tablename WHERE NOT fieldname IS NULL ORDER BY fieldname;`

However, if you want a new value to be available for next record for a continuous or datasheet form, the record must be committed to table and then requery the combobox. Record is committed when: 1. close table/query/form; or 2. move to another record; or 3. run code to save. So code in the form Current event like:
`Me.comboboxname.Requery`

Another option is to have lookup table for the combobox RowSource and set the comobobox LimitToList property to Yes. Then code in the combobox NotInList event to allow new value input by user to be saved to lookup table. Review: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845736.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not being clear... i have however managed to fix this by pointing  the row source to a table. This has allowed me to be able to do a selection on existing entries on the table and also "allow" adding new data using the same combobox.

thanks.